# Is it possible to get a file stream using exec with another command?

Tags: php, download

I need the file stream.

For example

```
private function faviconFoundExec($url)
{
    exec('wget ' . $url . ' -O ../favicons/test.jpg 2>&1', $output);
}
```

will save the actual file, but I need the file stream, the same thing that `file_get_contents` would return as below.

```
private function faviconFoundGet($url)
{
    return @file_get_contents( $url );
}
```

I'm looking at [passthru](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) but the documentation is a bit unclear.

Comment: How about fopen() http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php. Or are you looking for file()? What is it that file_get_contents() lacks?

Comment: any reason you have to use exec and not use builtin file handling functionality?

Comment: For some reason, I've found after hundreds of downloads that `wget` has more access than `file_get_contents()` and `exec()`, that is why I'm forced to use it, and add the complexity of having to call it from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a stream from a command with proc_open

```
$descriptorspec = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),   // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),   // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
    2 => array("pipe", "w")    // stderr is a pipe that the child will write to
);

$cmd = 'wget -qO- ' . $url;

$process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes, realpath('./'), array());

$contents = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);

fclose($pipes[1]);

// It is important that you close any pipes before calling
// proc_close in order to avoid a deadlock
proc_close($process);
```

Comment: @cadegalt you are right. I fixed wget to point to stdout. Just tested this and it works

Comment: its a shortcut for '-q -O-', the q makes wget quiet and the -O- redirects to stdout. http://askubuntu.com/a/168581/318869